# How to hide review section from google map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have embedded Google map on my wordpress website. When i see page then it on map on top left corner it shows a box with location name, address, reviews etc.

Now my question is how can i hide only *review section* from that box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided in your question, I'm assuming that you have one static location that shows up with all its details, you can remove the review section using Jquery but that will be complex, why don't you use the [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Also can you provide more details as to what you are trying to achieve ?
I'll be able to help you in a better way then.